# How to instantiate an object that is accessible by the functions of mainwindow?

Tags: c++, qt, oop, object, instance

I'd like to make a "Player" object that I can access with the functions of the mainwindow, like button click actions.

If I do it this way it won't be in scope:

```
void MainWindow::on_btn_newgame_clicked()
{ 
    Player p;
}

void MainWindow::on_btn_north_clicked()
{
      p->location_y++;
}
```

I tried instantiating globally but then I could not refer to p.

How and where should I do this?

Comment: if you don't want to use member variable you can pass it through signals and catch it in slot where signal ans slot are user defined.

Comment: Please don't add markers or tags to your titles. If you've solved this yourself, add an (detailed) answer so others can benefit. If James' post is what helped you, consider marking it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want access to state within a class then that state needs to be a member of the class.

Note: This is not unique to Qt.

For example:

```
class Foo
{
    public:
        void memberFunction()
        {
            p->getName(); // This member function may access member data
        }

    private:
        Player* mPlayer; // This is a class member
};
```

Comment: yes, just add the code "Player p;" within the "class MainWindow{ ... }" code in the mainwindow.h file